# Copy the last three lines of a text file in python?

Tags: python, list, text

I'm new to python and the way it handles variables and arrays of variables in lists is quite alien to me. I would normally read a text file into a vector and then copy the last three into a new array/vector by determining the size of the vector and then looping with a for loop a copy function for the last size-three into a new array.

I don't understand how for loops work in python so I can't do that.

so far I have:

```
    #read text file into line list
            numberOfLinesInChat = 3
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "r")
    lines = text_file.readlines()
    text_file.close()
    writeLines = []
    if len(lines) > numberOfLinesInChat:
                    i = 0
        while ((numberOfLinesInChat-i) >= 0):
            writeLine[i] = lines[(len(lines)-(numberOfLinesInChat-i))]
                            i+= 1

    #write what people say to text file
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(writeLines)
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: `print >> my_file,"\n".join(lines[-3:])`

Comment: Joran's comment only works for versions older than Python 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the last three lines of a file efficiently, use `deque`:

```
from collections import deque

with open('somefile') as fin:
    last3 = deque(fin, 3)
```

This saves reading the whole file into memory to slice off what you didn't actually want.

To reflect your comment - your complete code would be:

```
from collections import deque

with open('somefile') as fin, open('outputfile', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(deque(fin, 3))
```

Comment: waouh ! I was not aware of this trick. How does it work internally ? Is the reader reading line by line and keeping only the last three lines ? I mean like I would have write in a more verbose mode : lines = [] for row in lines :  lines.append(row) lines = lines[-3:]

Comment: This looks good, will it work if the file contains less than 3 lines ?

Comment: @Zac if there's not 3 lines - you'll get the remainder

Comment: @MrDave `collections.deque` can is an ummm, "double ended queue" - it also has a maxsize which it can fit into object space, so that a new entry drops from the queue the earliest.... So fed an iterator it does just that...

Comment: When I write last3 to a file I have to use str(last3) or I get a string buffer error, but if I do that I get a load of extra deque and max len characters ? How do I just write the /n terminated strings from last3 ?

Comment: will the updated answer not cause issues because the input file and output file are the same file?

Comment: @Zac you want to modify the file inplace?

Comment: To explain what I'm doing : I have an IRC client open and every time someone writes a line I want that to go to the bottom line of a text file but the top line to be removed when there are more than 4 lines.

Comment: Then just keep it in a `deque` - I don't understand why we're even dealing with files...

Comment: The file is read by a third party flash application that reads the text file and displays it as text on a desktop broadcast using desktop broadcast software.

Comment: @Zac that's a completely new question - the one you asked has been solved by multiple people - feel free to ask another question and **include** that information next time

Comment: If you get time to look at the new question I'd appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648578/append-a-text-line-to-a-file-and-remove-the-first-one-if-there-are-more-than-4-l

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're ok to hold all of the file lines in memory, you can slice the list of lines to get the last x items. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html and search for 'slice notation'.

```
def get_chat_lines(file_path, num_chat_lines):
    with open(file_path) as src:
        lines = src.readlines()
        return lines[-num_chat_lines:]


>>> lines = get_chat_lines('Output.txt', 3)
>>> print(lines)
... ['line n-3\n', 'line n-2\n', 'line n-1']
```

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question, my guress is that you had an index error you should replace the line writeLine[i] with writeLine.append( ). After that, you should also do a loop to write the output :

```
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for row in writeLine :
    text_file.write(row)
text_file.close()
```

May I suggest a more pythonic way to write this ? It would be as follow :

```
with open("Input.txt") as f_in, open("Output.txt", "w") as f_out :
    for row in f_in.readlines()[-3:] :
        f_out.write(row)
```

Comment: So a more pythonic way is ... nothing?

Comment: lol. I was struggling to have a nice indentation for the code.

Comment: one more point : if there is less than three lines, there is no pb and the code will write only the lines needed.

Comment: I can't understand that bottom example. I would like to read the bottom three lines and then re-write them with an addtional appended line to the same file and I'm not sure where the input.txt would come in. To give you some context to the problem, the extra line is supplied by IRC chat and I basically want a text file that is updated to contain only the last 4 lines of IRC chat in it.

Comment: sorry, please replace Input.txt with somefile. The with ... enforce that at the exit of the blocl, the two files will be closed. The f_in.readlines() return all the lines read from somefile, truncated to the last three ones [-3:]. Last the loop over the resulting list is writing every line in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
lines = [ l for l in open("Output.txt")]
file = open('Output.txt', 'w')
file.write(lines[-3:0])
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little clearer if you do not know python syntax.

lst_lines = lines.split()

This will create a list containing all the lines in the text file.

Then for the last line you can do:

last = lst_lines[-1]
secondLAst = lst_lines[-2]
etc... list and string indexes can be reached from the end with the '-'.

or you can loop through them and print specific ones using:

## start = start line, stop = where to end, step = what to increment by.

for i in range(start, stop-1, step):
    string = lst_lines[i]

then just write them to a file.