# Print last 20 bash history using python and save in pdf file

Tags: python, linux, bash, fpdf

This code print all the bash history but i have to print last 20 bash history.How can i do that?

```
import fpdf

pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=14)

for history in open('.bash_history'):
    pdf.write(8,history)

pdf.output("bash.pdf")
```

Comment: This might help: [Get last n lines of a file with Python, similar to tail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136168/3776858) or [Copy the last three lines of a text file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15647467/3776858)

Comment: Note that .bash_history is only the history last time it was saved. There may be newer commands in an ongoing session, so this utility will probably only be useful in a startup script. You would emit the bash command `history` for the latest history.

Answer (score 1):

The `.bash_history` file contains the entire history in order. You could simply load the file in a python list and then splice the list as per your requirements.

For Example, the following snippet will print the last 20 statements from the history file:

`print list(open('{PATH}/.bash_history'))[-20:]`